# Django unittest: threads in TestCase do not see the records but TransactionTestCase ones do

Tags: django, unit-testing

Given this code:

```
class ImportTest(TestCase):

    account = None

    def test_atomic(self):

        def import_task():
            print Account.objects.all()

        threads = []
        self.account = Account.objects.create(name='abc')
        for i in range(10):
            t = threading.Thread(target=import_task)
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()

        for t in threads:
            t.join()
```

The threads prints empty record set, but if I make it to extend `TransactionTestCase` as below:

```
class ImportTest(TransactionTestCase):

    account = None

    def test_atomic(self):

        def import_task():
            print Account.objects.all()

        threads = []
        self.account = Account.objects.create(name='abc')
        for i in range(10):
            t = threading.Thread(target=import_task)
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()

        for t in threads:
            t.join()
```

This will print out the record created.

Could someone please explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `TestCase` runs inside of a transaction (this is an implementation detail designed to improve performance), you shouldn't use it for anything that is itself testing or relying on transactions. This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase).

What's happening in this case is probably database- and isolation-level-dependent, but my guess is that: the test is running inside of an open transaction because you're using `TestCase`; that transaction remains open until the test is over and it's rolled back; the threads are creating their own connections to the database; and due to the isolation level they are not able to see the object created in the still-open main transaction.

The good news is that you've found the solution: use `TransactionTestCase`. The test process will run in the regular autocommit mode, so the `create()` commits to the database before the other threads do their lookups.

Comment: Lifesaver! I wish I had found this an hour ago. The only problem left is that the threads appear to not close their connections properly so test db deletion fails.